# What is this space called in general topology?

Tags: general-topology, notation

I am self-studying the general topology these day and find that the third axiom of the [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Open_set_definition) $(X,\tau)$ defined by open set is:

For any finite collection of $U_i \in \tau$, the intersection of $U_i$ is still a member of $\tau$.

Now I am wondering is there any space$(X,\tau)$ such that satisfying the following conditions:

$1)\emptyset , X \in \tau$

$2)$For any finite or infinite collection of $U_i \in \tau$, the union of $U_i$ is still a member of $\tau$.

$3)$For any finite or infinite collection of $U_i \in \tau$, the intersection of $U_i$ is still a member of $\tau$.

I come up with space $(X,2^X)$ satisfying this condition but I cannot find non-trivial one satisfying such condition.

Does such a space exists?  What name is it?

Comment: According to the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867861/in-which-topologies-do-open-sets-maintain-open-under-countable-or-arbitrary-inte) they are called Alexandrov spaces.

Comment: If $\pi$ is any partition of $X$ then the set of unions of its parts is a topology on $X$. If you add in the condition of being closed under complements then they're called [fields of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets) it would seem.

Comment: If the set of open sets is closed under arbitrary intersection, then the arbitrary union of closed sets is closed (de Morgan's law). So any space with this property in which all one-point sets are closed has the discrete topology, to give you an idea of what a non-trivial example looks like.

Comment: @florence Yes that is it.  So it should not be defined by open set?

Comment: @ZackNi Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @florence I mean what is the motivation to define the Alexandrov spaces? As far as I know, the motivation to define the topological space is that we have open set property (i.e. the finite intersection of open set is still a open set and the infinite union of open set is an open set). The motivation of Alexandrov space seemingly is that the incomplete of third axiom of topological space. So it is not of any meaning when it comes to the open set. Is my understanding correct?