# Intersection of open sets is an open set

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I studying topology by reading the  “Topology without Tears” written by Sidney Morris. One can easily find the book in pdf.

I know that the intersection of open sets is not always an open set. However, I was trying to find topologies that verify that. I came up with $\{ \emptyset, \mathbb{N} \}$ and all the sets whose elements are only powers of 2.

Can you give some other examples and what conditions such topologies must have to satisfy this property?

Comment: I don't understand your example.

Comment: For your second question see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867861/in-which-topologies-do-open-sets-maintain-open-under-countable-or-arbitrary-inte.

Comment: Apart from the empty set and the set of natural numbers, any other set only has numbers of the form $2^j$ for some $j\in J\subset\mathbb{N}$. It certainly helped, thank you.

Comment: That still makes no sense. It is not clear what sets you are talking about and even what topology you are talking about.

Comment: @QiZhu $\tau=\{ \emptyset, \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{ \bigcup_{J\subset\mathbb{N}} \{2^j | j\in J \}\}$

Comment: That is not a counterexample. (Also, you have to state that the underlying set is $\mathbb{N}$.)

Comment: @QiZhu I thought it was understandable from the context. Why is not it a counterexample?

Comment: You should rather ask why it should be a counterexample. Your topology consists of only three sets, there is no way to form (non-trivial) infinite intersections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113637/discussion-between-gio-and-qi-zhu).

Answer (score 4):

The only Hausdorff (or even $T_1$) topological spaces in which intersections of open set are always open are the discrete ones. Any set is  a union of singletons (which are closed) and so any set is an intersection of open sets. So every set is open.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces in which any intersection of open sets is open are called [Alexandrov spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology). You will find several characterizations of these spaces if you follow this link, in particular their connections with preorders via the specialization preorder.

Answer (score 0):

OK so the real numbers with the usual topology also show this. Let us think about the intersection of all open sets $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ can be any real number. This intersection must be $\{0\}$ because let us say that some $x \neq 0$ is in there then we just need to choose $\epsilon$ with magnitude less than $x$, $x$ will not be in $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ so $x$ could not have been in the intersection. Of course single element sets in the reals are closed and not open so $\{0\}$ is not open.

Cleary there is nothing special about $0$ in this example i.e. we could pick the intersection of all the intervals $(y-\epsilon, y+\epsilon)$ and this would just be $\{y\}$

Comment: This is certainly a counterexample, but can you give an example different from those above?

Comment: We can think about the intersection of all open circles diameter $\epsilon$ in $R^{2}$. Or really all open balls in $R^{n}$. In each case, the intersection is the single point set consisting of just the origin.

Comment: but you are considering $\{0\}$ an element of your topology, right?

Comment: So it is a set but not an open set so not strictly a member of the topology (because that often refers to just the open sets).